# How to write a transparent wrapper to terminal application?

Tags: python, linux, console, tty, pty

Wrapper should handle special control characters and do something but otherwise not interfere with the actual application. (trying to build a tmux like app)

So far I have the below modifying example in doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pty.html#example

```
import pty
import os

def handle_special_cmd(data):
    # TODO
    raise NotImplementedError

def inread(fd):
    data = os.read(fd, 1024)
    if b'\x02' in data: # ctrl B
        return handle_special_cmd(data)
    return data

def main():
    cmd="vim"
    pty.spawn(cmd, stdin_read=inread)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

The above code works but the vim opened does not cover the entire terminal window. It starts vim with reduced rows and columns [image: bad vim]

If I just type vim from the shell it works fine:
[image: good vim]

Why does this occur and how to fix it? My goal is not just fix the rows and columns but the wrapper should be truely transparent except trap the special ctrl character and do some stuff. whatever tty / colors and other settings the current shell has should be passed on to the actual executable. It should work as if I typed `vim`. (Linux specific solution is fine. Need not work in all posix. If it needs a c extension is also fine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window size is, uniquely, a property of the PTY itself. You can get and set it using the `TIOCGWINSZ` and `TIOCSWINSZ` ioctls:

```
import sys, fcntl, termios, struct

buf = bytearray(4)
fcntl.ioctl(sys.stdin.fileno(), termios.TIOCGWINSZ, buf)
(h, w) = struct.unpack("HH", buf)
print("Terminal is {w} x {h}".format(w=w, h=h))

[...]

fcntl.ioctl(child_pty.fileno(), termios.TIOCSWINSZ, struct.pack("HH", h, w))
```

Comment: Is there anything else other than window size that needs to be set on child_pty? Is there a way to just clone the current settings?

Comment: There's some other settings that you can get/set with [`termios.tcgetattr`/`tcsetattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/termios.html#termios.tcgetattr), but most of them are irrelevant for virtual PTYs, or are almost always left at the defaults. But the window size is handled separately, so you have to do the TIOC{G,S}WINSZ dance anyway.

Comment: Does not seem to work. Not sure if I am doing right: https://pastebin.com/raw/PjBpeZnP

Comment: @balki The "G" in `TIOCGWINSZ` stands for "Get". To set the window size (line 31), you need to use `TIOCSWINSZ` -- in which the first "S" stands for "Set". With that change, your script works perfectly.

Comment: My bad.. Thanks!

Comment: @balki how do you retrieve the pid? pty.spawn is calling waitpid

Comment: @MechanTOurS No idea. Didn't work on this recently